# How to Start Jquery Animation When Hidden Div is Called?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a hidden div in which I have a jquery running a typewriter animation. I was wondering how I can ge the animation to start once the div is revealed? At the moment when the div is revealed the type is already there.

Here is whats essentially happening now http://jsfiddle.net/caW8d/

```
$(document).ready(function()                         
/*-----------------FADE EFFECT --------------------*/
    {   var synopsis = $('#synopsis');
function runIt() {
   synopsis.animate({opacity:'+=1'}, 1000);
   synopsis.animate({opacity:'-=0.9'}, 2000, runIt).delay(2000);
}
       runIt(); 

    $("#trigger1").mouseover(function () {
   $("#somethingThere").fadeIn('slow');
});
    $("#trigger1").mouseout(function() {
    $("#somethingThere").fadeOut('slow');
});
    $("#trigger1").click(function () {
   $("#caption").fadeIn('slow');
});
    $("#caption").click(function () {
   $("#caption").hide();
});

/*-----------------TYPERWRITER EFFECT --------------------*/    
      $.fn.typer = function(options) {
        var defaults = {speed: 50},
            settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        return this.each(function(e,options){
            var el = $(this), 
                text = el.html(), 
                chars = 0, 
                timeout = null, 
                tw = function() {
                    el.html(text.substr(0, chars));
                    chars += 1;
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){tw();}, settings.speed);
                    if(text.length === chars){clearTimeout(timeout);}
                };

            el.html("");
            tw();
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$(function(){
    $('div').typer({speed:25});

    });
```

And here is what the animation should look like http://jsfiddle.net/yMYgZ/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.typer = function(options) {
        var defaults = {speed: 50},
            settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        return this.each(function(e,options){
            var el = $(this), 
                text = el.html(), 
                chars = 0, 
                timeout = null, 
                tw = function() {
                    el.html(text.substr(0, chars));
                    chars += 1;
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){tw();}, settings.speed);
                    if(text.length === chars){clearTimeout(timeout);}
                };

            el.html("");
            tw();
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$(function(){
    $('div').typer({speed:25});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The revealing/hiding jquery methods all have callbacks.  Assuming you want to call the `typer` plugin after the element with `id="#somethingThere` has faded in as an example:

```
 $('#somethingThere').fadeIn(100, function() {
    $('div').typer({speed:25});
 });
```

Documentation example for fadeIn: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

The function will execute after the fadeIn has occurred.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I'm not sure I'm doing it properly. I tried using $("#trigger1").click(function () {
   $("#caption").fadeIn(100, function(){
    div.typer({speed:25});
 }); to no avail

Comment: I had a typo in my answer with the div which was just updated.  In order to call your plugin after the fadeIn is what I demonstrated in the answer.  You could replace the `$('div').typer({speed:25})` with the code in the answer and it should animate the typer after the somethingThere fades in.

Comment: I did gather that. I 've tried `$("#trigger1").click(function () {
    $("#caption").fadeIn('slow',function(){
 $("div").typer({speed:25});});
 });`  It just ends up making the whole thing glitchy